# How to use a do-while loop in Java?

Tags: java

I want to print a triangle with a `do while` loop.

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
```

I have been able to print it using a `while` loop as follows:

```
class Whileloop
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        int i = 1;
        while (i <= 4)
        {
            System.out.print("\n");     
            int j = 1;
            while (j <= i)
            {
                System.out.print(j);
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I print it using a `do while` loop?

Comment: Hi! As it currently stands, your question is not in a desired format on StackOverflow! You need to be clear in what your problem is and explain what you tried and where you failed. Just pasting some code and expecting help is not going to work.

Comment: Sir Raul Rene i have not passed someones code

Comment: I think he is trying to build ascii triangle?

Comment: its my code i have a problem that i have made it with while loop but i have got an assignment from my sir he says me tried to make it with do while loop he didn't explain that loop to me

Comment: can anyone help me please how i make this triangle with do while loop

Comment: @Mufasil what have you tried? Just replace the while by a do-while and see what happens

Comment: sir Heuster i have tried to make a triangle with while loop but i have not study do-while loop yet but my sir tells me try it so i have tried it my infinite loop is comming but i am not able to get exact result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the do-while equivalent of your program.

In do while the code inside the `{}` block executed at least once before checking the condition. And the condition is checked after execution of that block.

For Complete Tutorial On do-while loop, refer this **[link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)**

Structure:

```
       do{
          //do here
       }while(booleanExpression);
```

This  is your do-while equivalent: See comments in the code

```
    class Tester
    {
       public static void main (String args[]){

          int i=1;
          do{                          //block started with out checking condition
         System.out.print("\n");     
         int j=1;
         do {                       //inner loop starts
           System.out.print(j);
           j++;
           }while(j<=i);             //condition check for inner loop
           i++;
          }while(i<=4);             //condition check for outer loop
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, take a look at the [while and do-while documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html). If you tried looking over you would have probably figured out the answer yourself.

The `do-while` statement differs from the `while` statement that it checks the condition at the bottom of the loop.

In your case, the solution is pretty simple:

```
    int i=1;
    do {
        System.out.print("\n");     
        int j=1;

        do {
            System.out.print(j);
            j++;
        } while (j<=i);

        i++;
     } while(i <= 4);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yea as suggested by Heuster just replace while with do while,

Instead of

```
    while(condition)
    {
      //code
    }
```

It will be

```
    do
    {
       //code
    }while(condition);
```